# $X\times Y$ is Locally Compact

Tags: general-topology

I need to show that if $X$ and $Y$ are locally compact, then so is $X\times Y$.
I am really slow on this so be patient with me.
Any help is appreciated.

I need to find a compact nbd for each $x\times y$ in $X \times Y$

Now since $X$ and $Y$ are locally compact then for each $x \in X$ and $y\in Y$ exist neighborhoods of $x$ and $y$ respectively $U_x$ and $U_y$ that are compact.

Comment: There are several slightly different definitions of local compactness; which is yours?

Comment: oh I just made changes and it deleted it. Mine is that for each point of the space exists a nbd that is compact

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I’ll get you started. Let $p=\langle x,y\rangle$ be an arbitrary point of $X\times Y$. $X$ is locally compact, so $x$ has a compact nbhd $H\subseteq X$. Similarly, $y$ has a compact nbhd $K\subseteq Y$. Now $H\times K$ is certainly compact and certainly contains $p$. Can you show that $H\times K$ is a nbhd of $p$?

Remember, $H$ is a nbhd of $x$ in $X$ if and only if there is an open set $U\subseteq X$ such that $x\in U\subseteq H$.

Comment: @ Brian Could intH xIntK be my U for p in X x Y?

Comment: @Klara: It could indeed: it’s a basic open set in the product, it certainly contains $p$, and it’s certainly a subset of $H\times K$.

Comment: @ Brian Thank you so much, so I'm done then:) Thank you again.

Comment: @Klara: You’re welcome. (Not so hard as you feared, was it?)

Comment: You helped me a lot. Thank you again.

Comment: @Klara: Any time. Topology questions are my favorite.